# $2D$ Maximum Likelihood Fit

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, fitting, likelihood

I have read a couple of places that it is possible to do a $2D$ (or $3D$) maximum likelihood fit, but I can't seem to understand how this would work. Suppose I'm considering a probability distribution function depending on $2$ observable variables, $x$ and $y$, given a multi-dimensional set of variable parameters, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, ..., PDF($x_i,y_i$|$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots$).

I would say that I have a good understanding of the ideas behind a maximum likelihood fit, but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around a multi-dimensional maximum likelihood fit.

How do I understand how a $2D$ maximum likelihood fit to determine the best estimate of the parameters $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ works?

Comment: Everything about it is the same as unidimensional case. What is unclear for you?

Answer (score 0):

Maximum likelihood is about learning

$$\hat{\theta} \in \{\arg\max_{\theta \in \Theta}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln f(x_i|\theta)\}$$

Notice that $\Theta$ need not be of just one dimension and it can be of multiple dimension.

The whole idea is to optimize a quantity and techniques from calculus or numerical optimization might be involved. For smooth cases, we typically begins by exploring the stationary point of the objective function.

Comment: Likelihood is not mean but product. I guess you forgot log? The 1/n constant is not a part of the definition.

Comment: I must admit, I still do not see where 2D fit comes in? I understand that , the parameters we want to estimate, can be of several dimensions. But we would still do a fit around a single parameter at a time, right? And then possibly re-fit to the remaining parameters. However, what happens if f does not only depend on x, but also y?

Comment: We solve them simultaneously rather than one parameter at a time.

Comment: [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/191/) is an example where the parameters are $\mu$ and $\sigma$. In that example, while the derivative with respect to $\mu$ can be solved independently, we should view the two first order constraints as a system of equations that we want to satisfy.

Comment: [here](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2613&context=etd) , a more complicated example where MLE for the parameters of beta distributed is staed in equation $(2.3)$ and $(2.4)$ and numerical method is used to find them.

Comment: So is that what defines a 2D maximum likelihood fit? Instead of requiring d(lnf)/d(θ1)=0 for one parameter at a time, we require d(lnf)/d(θ1)=0 at the same time as d(lnf)/d(θ2)=0? Possibly, I am just getting lost in where the distinguishing between 1D and 2D (or higher) is

Comment: We have to satisfy a simultaneous system of equations where $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_1} =0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_2} =0$. Sometimes, you can solve one of the parameter first but this is not always the case as shown in the second link.

Comment: I think I get it now. The links are helpful too, so thank you :)